# Event listener not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I want my button's class name to show up when I click on it, but nothing is showing up.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(button.className);
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Rock Papers Scissors</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
        <button class="rock">Rock</button>
        <button class="paper">Paper</button>
        <button class="scissors">Scissors</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've omitted some of the full code, but you can find it here if required: https://github.com/pranit-garg/odin-rock-papers-scissors

Thanks so much for the help in advance!

Comment: What's the issue? The code here seems to work correctly?

Comment: Your sample code is working as intended. There is class name printed out in DevTools console

Comment: Where do you want to display className when clicking on buttons???

Comment: You could add a [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute to your script tag: `<script src="javascript.js" defer></script>`, so it runs after the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the script tag just before the end of the body section. If its in the head, and you do not delay its execution until page load with adding an event listener to the window, then it won't bind to any buttons because there are no buttons yet when your code is executed, as it executes in the head, when body part of your document is not yet rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Rock Papers Scissors</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
        <button class="rock">Rock</button>
        <button class="paper">Paper</button>
        <button class="scissors">Scissors</button>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that works, thanks for the help! Another solution I found that might be helpful to others is adding "defer" to the script tag to rewrite it as: 

<script src="javascript.js" defer></script>

that way I can keep the code in the head